# Error While Installing JSF Facet in Eclipse Project

Tags: eclipse

Error While Installing JSF Facet in Eclipse Project

[image]

**Detailed exception trace from .metadata/.log**

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core 4 0 2018-10-04 18:48:27.943
!MESSAGE Failed while installing JavaServer Faces 2.2.
!STACK 0

java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.eclipse.jst.jsf.core.internal.project.facet.JSFFacetInstallDelegate.resolveConfigPath(JSFFacetInstallDelegate.java:313)
        at org.eclipse.jst.jsf.core.internal.project.facet.JSFFacetInstallDelegate.createConfigFile(JSFFacetInstallDelegate.java:331)
        at org.eclipse.jst.jsf.core.internal.project.facet.JSFFacetInstallDelegate.execute(JSFFacetInstallDelegate.java:130)
        at org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.internal.FacetedProject.callDelegate(FacetedProject.java:1477)
        at org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.internal.FacetedProject.modifyInternal(FacetedProject.java:441)
        at org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.internal.FacetedProject.mergeChangesInternal(FacetedProject.java:1181)
        at org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.internal.FacetedProject.access$2(FacetedProject.java:1117)
        at org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.internal.FacetedProject$5.run(FacetedProject.java:1099)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2313)
        at org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.internal.FacetedProject.mergeChanges(FacetedProject.java:1109)
        at org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.internal.FacetedProjectWorkingCopy.commitChanges(FacetedProjectWorkingCopy.java:2020)
        at org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.ui.internal.FacetsPropertyPage$4.run(FacetsPropertyPage.java:232)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2313)
        at org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.ui.internal.FacetsPropertyPage$5.run(FacetsPropertyPage.java:246)
        at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:122)

!SESSION 2018-10-05 10:56:32.004 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=3.6.1.201408250818-RELEASE-e44
java.version=1.7.0_51
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.springsource.sts.ide
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -product org.springsource.sts.ide
```

Comment: Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if there is a more detailed message.

Comment: @greg-449 Thanks! I found the detailed exception trace and updated in the question. What next?!

Comment: I don't see any update to the question

Answer (score 0):

Is this project a "Dinamic Web Project"? If so, you have to select a "Dynamic web module version" 2.5 or higher, because JavaServer Faces 2.2 requires this version.

You can also try to delete the project (save to another location first, just to be safe) and import it as a maven project, adding the facets latter or adjusting your pom.xml example:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.13</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.13</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

You can also check your web.xml as picture below.

[image]

It should be like the code below, according to your "Dynamic Web Module" (see version 3.1 and web-app_3_1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" 
         version="3.1">
```

Comment: "If so, you have to select a "Dynamic web module version" 2.5 or higher, because JavaServer Faces 2.2 requires this version." 
- I've already selected 3.0. It is visible in the screenshot.

I found the detailed exception trace and updated in the question

Comment: In that case, I still suggest you to remove and re-import the project as a maven project. If your version is correct, then maven will download the missing parts of it. Give it a chance.